# Create instance of a class within a method of another class

Tags: c++, class, qt5

this is probably a really basic C++ question but I simply cannot find out a way to properly do this:

I need to create some instances of class "QPluginLoader" within a method of my GUI class and want to store these instances within a QList. The QPluginLoader instances have to be available throughout the whole GUI class.
But whenever I try to access a QPluginLoader through my QList the program crashes. I assume that is because once out of the scope where I instantiated the QPluginLoader class, it is destroyed, so it's not available outside of the method where I created the QPluginLoader and stored it into the QList.

But how do I make the instance available in the whole class?

Here is what I tried:

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void onThreadTerminated();

private:
    bool loadPlugins();
    QList<QPluginLoader*> loaderList;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
bool MainWindow::loadPlugins()
{
    QDir pluginsDir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    pluginsDir.cd("plugins");

    foreach (QString fileName, pluginsDir.entryList(QDir::Files))
    {
        QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
        QObject* plugin = pluginLoader.instance();

        if (plugin)
        {
            loaderList.push_back(&pluginLoader);
            pluginCount++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

last but not least, the slot which crashes my program

```
// SLOT
void MainWindow::onThreadTerminated()
{
    while (!loaderList.isEmpty()) {
       if(loaderList.takeFirst()->isLoaded()) loaderList.takeFirst()->unload();
    }
    loaderList.clear();
}
```

Comment: If you want to store a `QPluginLoader` then store a `QPluginLoader` and not a `QPluginLoader *`.

Comment: I tried this, but it fails compiling, saying "'QPluginLoader::QPluginLoader': cannot access private member declared in class 'QPluginLoader'" at the point where i am using QList<QPluginLoader>::takeFirst()

Comment: On an unrelated point, why do you use `QList` for the container? Unless you regularly insert or remove elements in the middle of the container, your default container should always be a vector ([`QVector`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) if you want a Qt container). Even [the Qt documentation itself](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#details) (for *all* core containers) says "QVector should be your default first choice".

Comment: thanks for the note, I changed it to be QVector now. Haven't thought about that, but yea problem still remains. I am unable to create a container of `QPluginList` instead of `QPluginList*`

Comment: `QPluginLoader` is a `QObject` which means it is neither copyable nor movable. You can make it movable by storing a `std::unique_ptr` to it. Alternatively use `std::list` with `.emplace_back`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these two lines in the `loadPlugins` function

```
QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
...
loaderList.push_back(&pluginLoader);
```

The first define the *local* object `pluginLoader`. The second pushes a pointer to that local object into the container.

The problem is that when the loop iterates (or ends), the life-time of `pluginLoader` ends and it is destructed, the pointer to it becomes invalid.

It seems to me that you should not have a container of plugin loaders, but of the actual plugins themselves.

If you really want the plugin loader in the container, you need to create those dynamically with `new`, or at least use smart pointers for it. Or, as mentioned in a comment to your question, use a container of `QPluginLoader` *objects*.

Comment: I tried the method with `new` and it still crashed somehow, until I noticed another problem in my code: I was using the List method `QList::takeLast()` which does not (as I thought) simply give me the pointer to the Last element, but also deletes it! I only had one element in the list, and when I used "takeLast()" the second time it would crash because the list was empty. I exchanged takeLast() to simply be `QList::last()` which is actually the method I was looking for. This seems to work now

Comment: Someone mentioned that using `new` is not really safe and induces resource leaks. To be honest I don't really want to manually deal with those pointers (i.e. making sure they get deleted once not used anymore). Is the solution to simply use smart pointers then? I have not really worked with them so far.

Comment: @Jens If possible, don't use pointers at all. But if you do, then yes smart pointers relieve you of some of the problems of pointers (like having to manually delete them).

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (QString fileName, pluginsDir.entryList(QDir::Files))
{
    QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
```

`pluginLoader` will be destroyed at the next `}` and you keep a reference of this destroyed object in `loaderList`.

Allocate memory for `pluginLoader` dynamically using `new` and keep pointers to `QPluginLoader` in `loaderList`

Ofcourse you will have to remember to free the allocated memory for `QPluginLoader`s

Comment: This is prone to subtle bugs caused by resource leaks.